# In Xcode 9's new build system, how do I execute commands before the check dependencies phase?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an `foo.xcconfig` file that will have different values depending where in the world a developer is. Currently, we use a phase to create this file (which is imported by other config files). In the new build system, Xcode is now resolving the dependencies before I have a chance to create a dummy to satisfy the include.

This is easily solved for CI builds by doing the work before calling `xcodebuild`, but for local builds using the GUI, there does not seem to be a good solution.